# How can I sync class names when build react app with webpack?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, create-react-app, css-loader

I'm building a react web app using `create-react-app`.

As you know, there are default webpack settings on `create-react-app`. It has `css-loader` related settings, especially `webpack.config.prod.js` has `css-loader` settings like below.

```
{
    test: /\.css$/,
    loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract(
        Object.assign({
                fallback: {
                    loader: require.resolve('style-loader'),
                    options: {
                        hmr: false,
                    },
                },
                use: [{
                        loader: require.resolve('css-loader'),
                        options: {
                            importLoaders: 1,
                            minimize: true,
                            sourceMap: shouldUseSourceMap,
                            modules: true,
                            localIdentName: '[path][name]__[local]--[hash:base64:5]'
                        },
                    },
                    {
                        loader: require.resolve('postcss-loader'),
                        options: {
                            // Necessary for external CSS imports to work
                            // https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/issues/2677
                            ident: 'postcss',
                            plugins: () => [
                                require('postcss-flexbugs-fixes'),
                                autoprefixer({
                                    browsers: [
                                        '>1%',
                                        'last 4 versions',
                                        'Firefox ESR',
                                        'not ie < 9', // React doesn't support IE8 anyway
                                    ],
                                    flexbox: 'no-2009',
                                }),
                            ],
                        },
                    },
                ],
            },
            extractTextPluginOptions
        )
    ),
    // Note: this won't work without `new ExtractTextPlugin()` in `plugins`.
},
```

It creates an external css file about imported css files, which have the class names are transformed.

For example, If I import an css file in a node module like below,

```
import 'antd/dist/antd.min.css'
```

if there's a class definition `ant-input`, it becomes `node_modules-antd-dist-antd__ant-input--2iAqM` in created css file in actual build folder while my tags use still `ant-input` class.
So the result pages are not styled at all. How can I appropriately apply styles with this `css-loader` settings?

Answer (score 0):

Change the `options` portion as so:

```
// before
{
  loader: require.resolve('css-loader'),
  options: {
    importLoaders: 1,
  },
},
// after
{
  loader: require.resolve('css-loader'),
  options: {
    importLoaders: 1,
    modules: true,
    localIdentName: "[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]"  
  },
},
```

Do the same in your Webpack production config

```
// before
{
  loader: require.resolve('css-loader'),
  options: {
    importLoaders: 1,
    minimize: true,
    sourceMap: true,
   },
},
// after
{
  loader: require.resolve('css-loader'),
  options: {
    importLoaders: 1,
    modules: true,
    minimize: true,
    sourceMap: true,
   },
},
```

More info on [how to use css modules with create react app](https://medium.com/nulogy/how-to-use-css-modules-with-create-react-app-9e44bec2b5c2)